Module is missing in the dotenv library
so i installed nodejs using a flake version 21 it worked and installed couple dependencies along side with it, but dotenv won't work because of some missing dependencies.
**Edit ( not only dotenv now, but every dependencies installed by npm has missing some type of modules)
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:264
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/.../Nodejs/AltissiaAI - OpenAI/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js' imported from /home/nyxar/Programming/Coding/Nodejs/AltissiaAI - OpenAI/AI.js
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:264:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:924:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1148:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:390:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:234:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  url: 'file:///home/.../Nodejs/AltissiaAI%20-%20OpenAI/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js
}

Node.js v21.7.2

and here's the code it might be helpful:
import { config } from "dotenv";
import { inspect } from "util";
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import { login } from "./Methods/Login.mjs";
import { OpenAI } from "openai";
import { pageLogic } from "./Methods/PageLogic.mjs";
// import { nextLesson } from "./Methods/nextLesson.mjs";
// import { nextActivity } from "./Methods/nextActivity.mjs";
// import { completeExercise } from "./Methods/ExercisesLogic/Exercises.mjs";

config();
const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY });
openai.chat.completions;
const username = process.env.usrname;
const password = process.env.pass;

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(
  "https://app.ofppt-langues.ma/gw/api/saml/init?idp=https://sts.windows.net/dae54ad7-43df-47b7-ae86-4ac13ae567af/"
);

await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" });

await login(page, username, password);
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" });
await pageLogic(page, openai, inspect);

and i did npm fund and it was listed as installed:
nyxar@nixos ~/P/C/N/AltissiaAI - OpenAI (master)> npm fund AltissiaAI - OpenAI ├── https://dotenvx.com │   └── dotenv@16.4.5
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "npm": "^10.8.0",
    "openai": "^4.47.1",
    "puppeteer-core": "^22.9.0"
  }
}

nyxar@nixos ~/P/C/N/AltissiaAI - OpenAI> which npm
/nix/store/j095ldzx42w76hzyz6x42r8lpvikvn1j-nodejs-21.7.2/bin/npm
nyxar@nixos ~/P/C/N/AltissiaAI - OpenAI> which node
/nix/store/j095ldzx42w76hzyz6x42r8lpvikvn1j-nodejs-21.7.2/bin/node
nyxar@nixos ~/P/C/N/AltissiaAI - OpenAI> npm -v
10.5.0
nyxar@nixos ~/P/C/N/AltissiaAI - OpenAI> node -v
v21.7.2
nyxar@nixos ~/P/C/N/AltissiaAI - OpenAI>


Can you share your package.json? Those waitForNavigations look spurious. Keep navigations in goto only, or alongside a nav trigger click in Promise.all.

@ggorlen alr I'll add it, i just have an update, it's not only the dotenv that doesn't work but also the openai and puppeteer library, they all have missing dependencies even after i installed them

@ggorlen i did include everything you said

Maybe a path issue due the Your OS ? /home/.../Nodejs/AltissiaAI - OpenAI/ (the space between the words)

FYI you're importing config incorrectly. See https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv?tab=readme-ov-file#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import

I'm using yarn rn, it didn't work at all
